# Visualize Users Group Selection and Intersection

Tags: multi-selection, logic, permissions

I want to simplify the visualization of users' group permissions with intersections and unions.

The main challenge is to make a complex selection easy to read for non-technical users, and at the same time make it minimalistic. The expressions would be something like:
[image]

The number of groups included in the expression are variable so this can get quite long. My current idea is to keep it like natural language, but this can make expressions really long.

How can this experience be made simple?

Comment: Notion's filter system is pretty intuitive and powerful, perhaps it might inspire you...

Comment: @Nearoo Would help if you can post a _link_ detailing `Notion's filter`. Some like me don't know it

Comment: @hc_dev [Here](https://www.notion.so/Intro-to-databases-fd8cd2d212f74c50954c11086d85997e#9d78bd946c6541beace7b69ac9366497). I used an advanced technique called "google search".

Comment: @Nearoo Thank you! This Google filter seems superior to [mine,  used](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Notion%27s+filter+system) suggested [Filters in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology), which requested me asking 

Answer (score 2):

**Your statements are complex because they contain a lot of information**

Yes, natural language makes it easier to read, but it does not help with processing the 5 elements (desktop, mobile,...) and relations in one sentence. It is up to you to restrict the user to a more simple version of this, so it will be easier to comprehend. Look at email filters, for example (see image below).

**Some relations cannot be expressed in natural language**

For example, it is not clear to me if your statement includes Desktop users per-se or both desktop and mobile users have to belong to a group.

`Desktop AND (Mobile users who belong to ...)` or
`Desktop AND Mobile who belong to ...`

[image: email-filter]

Comment: I understand what you say, actually that's my problem :D I don't know how to improve the readability of the expression keeping it simple. The example of the email filters is good for the creation of the selection, but I'm not sure about how to translate it to a visualisation mode, keeping in mind that I need to show a list of expressions and using the filter format would make the list really complex. 
Anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Keeping it simple means making it shorter with less elements. You cannot expect to improve the readability of something just by "throwing a bunch of words and colors" at a super long SQL statement.

Comment: I know, I know. Because of that I'm asking ... I don't know how to simplify it keeping the readability. My example was not a proposed solution, was a visualisation of the problem.